# Difference between WebCommitDelay and IISCommitDelay

Tags: powershell, iis, web-administration

What is the difference between WebCommitDelay and IISCommitDelay?

MS docs says the same for both:
`Instructs the IIS configuration system to delay the commitment of changes.`

So what should I prefer and why? It looks like they have some differences indeed, because if I use WebCommitDelay, I can't use `New-WebApplication ... -Force` if the same application is exists, but I can do this if I use IISCommitDelay.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the IISAdministration PowerShell module which was a new way to manage IIS.

This module included numerous improvements over the existing WebAdministration cmdlets.

So the IISCommitDelay is the new method which is  used to management the IIS.

Detials, you could refer to this [article](https://blogs.iis.net/iisteam/introducing-iisadministration-in-the-powershell-gallery).